# Is there any image viewer with one-click rotation?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing

I am searching for a simple image viewer, like Shotwell or Eye of GNOME, but I need it to save the image every time I rotate it. Is there an image viewer which will save the image automatically?

I am looking for a GUI application.

Answer (score 1):

One tool that can do this is [exiftran](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/exiftran.1.html).

To install it use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install exiftran
```

If you'd like to do auto-rotation for all the images in a directory.  then you can do it with this command:

```
exiftran -ai *.jpeg
```

so all the .jpeg images presented in that directory will be rotated automatically and they will save the rotation too.